# gcc.exe: error: unknown argument: '-municode'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to build the OpenVPN GUI from source in an effort to customize it. I download the source code from Github and used the BUILD.rst instructions for building with Cygwin on Windows 7 (32-bit).

Here are the build instructions (https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn-gui/blob/master/BUILD.rst):

```
autoreconf -iv
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
make
```

and replace "x86_64" with "i686" if you are building for 32-bit Windows. These instructions work when using "x86_84", but after using make for 32-bit Windows I get the following errors:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/IEUser/openvpn-gui'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -D_UNICODE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA -DWINVER=_WIN32_WINNT -municode -g -O2 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-municode'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:544: main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/IEUser/openvpn-gui'
make: *** [Makefile:420: all] Error 2
```

I am new to creating and debugging MakeFiles. Has anyone else gotten this error or have any suggestions on where to research for a solution?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: What is the output of `gcc -dumpmachine`?

Comment: `-municode` is for x386 and x86-64 Windows only (at least according to the manpage of GCC), so do as @l'L'l suggests and post the ouput of `gcc -dumpmachine`

Comment: Have you run the configure script?  Is there a configure script?  Some of those `-D` options look suspiciously non-Unix-appropriate.\

Comment: @JonathanLeffler AFAIK Cygwin is only available for Windows. non-Unix-appropriate definitions aren't that bad then.

Comment: The `make` program being used, @Gerhardh, looks like XCode on a Mac (see `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make` for example).  As such, the Windows-specific definitions do look suspicious.  Using the Cygwin build instructions on a Mac may not be as successful as all that — judging from the fact that the question is asked, they're certainly not a slam dunk (it isn't 100% OK to use them).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK. Maybe I read his question wrong. I assumed he wants to build with Cygwin but this might be incorrect.

Comment: @Gerhardh: the OP hasn't been all that forthcoming about the target environment but the path quoted strongly indicates the Mac platform (if you work on it at all, as I do).  It's not unreasonable to have been caught off guard.

Comment: @M.M I get the same error using Cygwin on Windows 7 (32-bit) and Mac OSX 10.11.16. The build instructions are intended for Windows but I was curious about what would happen on my Mac.

Comment: @TiffanyMontgomery You won't get anywhere trying to build Windows programs on a Mac. (Well, unless you've installed a cross-compile version of mingw-w64 on the mac, which you haven't and shouldn't)

Comment: @M.M ok I edited the question to include the errors I'm getting on Cygwin

Comment: @I'L'I output is mingw32

Comment: @JonathanLeffer Gerhardh I apologize for the confusion. I should have posted my OS sooner. I edited the question. But deamentiaemundi has it right "-municode" isn't available for 32-bit Windows.

Comment: The project documentaiton indicates that you must use `mingw-w64` as the compiler.  Perhaps your cygwin installation has a different compiler; as requested previously the output of `gcc -dumpmachine` should show what you actually have